# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
`Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

`C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150116-5956-smcp65.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile`

`make clean Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.`

`make`

`Makefile:165: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop.`

`make failed, exit code 2`
```

This error occurs everytime i am creating a new rails application.After run the command `rails new Blog` i am getting this error.

Comment: Update RubyGems `gem update --system`, and try again.

Comment: Are you doing this in windows ?

Comment: yes i am doing this in windows

Comment: I have a similar issue and I downgraded gem from 2.5.1 to 2.3.0 and still having the issue. DevKit is installed and I am trying to install ruby-odbc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same error while doing a `bundle install`. Turns out [it's a known issue](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/977), but the fix isn't due out until [RubyGems 2.5](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/milestones/2.5). In the meantime, downgrading to v2.3.0 should be a suitable workaround:

```
> gem update --system 2.3.0
```